# Retorno de dados do banco para página PHP não retornando dados

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, pessoal.

Estou com uma página (index.php) que precisa retornar os dados do banco para ela. Tenho um .php (conexão.php) que efetua a conexão com o banco, veja:

```
$_SG['servidor'] = 'localhost';    // Servidor MySQL
$_SG['usuario'] = 'root';          // Usuário MySQL
$_SG['senha'] = 'XXXX';                // Senha MySQL
$_SG['banco'] = 'projetoqa';            // Banco de dados MySQL
$_SG['paginaLogin'] = '../login.php'; // Página de login
$_SG['tabela'] = 'usuarios';       // Nome da tabela onde os usuários são salvos
// ==============================
// ======================================
//   ~ Não edite a partir deste ponto ~
// ======================================
// Verifica se precisa fazer a conexão com o MySQL
if ($_SG['conectaServidor'] == true) {
  $_SG['link'] = mysql_connect($_SG['servidor'], $_SG['usuario'], $_SG['senha']) or die("MySQL: Não foi possível conectar-se ao servidor [".$_SG['servidor']."].");
  mysql_select_db($_SG['banco'], $_SG['link']) or die("MySQL: Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados [".$_SG['banco']."].");
}
// Verifica se precisa iniciar a sessão
if ($_SG['abreSessao'] == true)
  session_start();
```

A conexão sei que está OK, pois já utilizei outra função do código para inserir conteúdo nela. Porém, na página index.php onde preciso exibir resultados, não consigo. Veja o código:

```
<?php

        // Inclui o arquivo com o sistema de segurança
        require_once("php/conexao.php");

        // executa a query 
        $busca = "SELECT titulo FROM questoes";

        $resultado = mysql_query($busca);

        // Encerra a conexão
        mysql_close();
    ?>
```

E o local onde deve ser exibido o resultado:

```
<li><a href="#"><?php $resultado ?></a></li>
```

Fica em branco apenas! Nada aparece. Qual o problema deste caso? Olhei alguns fóruns e outros métodos de como realizar a busca, não consegui encontrar. O dado em questão que retorna ali, é apenas um título. Por exemplo "Como jogar videogame?"

Obrigado!

Comment: `OMG` amigo, fico logo com algumas dores de cabeça, só de tentar ler o teu código, porque tu definiste as Arrays de uma forma meio trabalhosa, apesar de a técnica já estar ultrapassada, ser pouco eficiente, e nada recomendada, tu complicaste mais ainda. Experimenta colocar um `echo $resultado`, tenho de analisar melhor o teu código.

Comment: Tentarei. Desculpe pela desorganização do código, realmente além de novo no PHP e SQL, estou ainda recém mexendo no código sem organiza-lo ainda.

Comment: Tente dar um var_dump($resultado) para ver o que está sendo retornado na variável e uma dica, as funções mysql_* estão depreciadas a partir da versão 5.5 do php, tente substituir por PDO ou mysqli_*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, antes de mais eu gostaria de lhe recomendar uma atualização do PHP para uma versão recente e estável.
Atualmente quase  ninguém mais usa o `MySQL` porque foi desapreciado oficialmente e é pouco seguro, recomendando então o `MySQLi`.

## Resposta

```
<?php

//Login do SQL
DEFINE("HOST", "localhost"); 
DEFINE("USR", "usuario");
DEFINE("PWD", "senha");
DEFINE("BD", "banco_de_dados");
// Ou $db = array("host"=>"localhost", "usr"=>"usuario", "pwd"=>"senha", "bd"=>"banco_de_dados");
// Ou $host = "localhost"; $usr = "usuario"; $pwd = "senha"; $bd = "banco_de_dados";

//Conexao
$conexao = mysqli_connect(HOST, USR, PWD, BD);
// $conexao = mysqli_connect($db["host"], $db["usr"], $db["pwd"], $db["bd"]);
// $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $usr, $pwd, $bd);


if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    //Encerra a conexao e mostra a mensagem com o erro    
    die("Erro: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Preparo da consulta SQL

$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT x FROM z");
if(!$sql){
    die("Erro: zzz");
}
//Looping para retornar os valores
while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    // Ou echo "Nome: " . $resultado["nome"];    
    ?>
    <!--
    Algum HTML aqui
    ex.:
    !-->
    <b>Nome: </b><?php echo $resultado["nome"]; ?>
    
    <?php
}

mysqli_free_result($sql);

mysqli_close($conexao);

?>
```

**OBS:** `Alguns dos comentários que inseri no código, são possíveis alternativas de como poderias escrever o código, apesar de ainda existirem várias outras que não coloquei.`

Outra coisa, é que, antes de tentares retornar o resultado de uma consulta com o `echo`, deves antes dizer ao `PHP` como selecionar, e quais resultados selecionar, utilizando a função com prefixo `mysqli_fetch_[aqui_o_metodo]`, podendo selecionar apenas 1 conjunto de valores, ou mesmo todos os conjuntos de valores existentes usando um `looping` e/ou sintaxes `SQL`.

E acima de tudo, desculpa a preguiça, e ignorância da minha parte, mas preferi escrever um código semelhante ao teu, do que tentar entender o teu :/

[PHP.NET](http://php.net) - Aqui podes encontrar vários exemplos, e formas recomendas de utilizar algumas funções.

Existem também sites próprios que falam e abordam sobre as formas recomendas de escrever consultas `SQL`.

Aqui no `StackOverflow` existem também várias perguntas já respondidas que te podem ajudar.

Comment: Edilson, muito obrigado pela ajuda e clareamento. Vou começar pesquisar sobre o MYSQLI. Confesso que sou novo e acabei buscando alguns exemplos de conexão SQL para brincar um pouco e entender mais como funciona. Acabei me embananando e pegando algo muito antigo. Refarei meu código buscando por esse novo método.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve utilizar um laço para exibir os dados da consulta.

Primeiro, verifique se sua consulta está realmente correta.

```
if (!$resultado ) {
    //se a consulta está incorreta, mostra erro
    die( "Erro na consulta: " . mysql_error() );<br>
}else{
    //você precisa utilizar um laço para pegar os resultados desta query
    //porque o metodo mysql_query() traz outros atributos além dos dados do banco 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //echo $row['campoDoBanco'];
   }
}
```